# Queue handling in HTTP server with heavy load

Tags: performance, http, webserver

Consider a web server under very heavy load, resulting in important lag (up to ~30s response time). I've noticed that if I asynchronously request the same page multiple times (e.g. send multiple requests before the previous ones are answered), responses don't necessarily come back in the order I sent them.

Can anyone explain how the server chooses which requests to handle first? It seems there is no obvious queueing, so what makes a request get picked instead of another?